# how to check for an attribute in an array in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to find whether a specific attribute is present or not with where statement that takes an array in ruby.

I tried like the below.

```
User.where(id: [1,2,3]).include?('address')
```

Answer (score 1):

`User.where(id: [1,2,3])` would return a relation (which behaves pretty much as an array, but that's another story). It means, that is consists of objects - instances of `User` class.

You check if this collection includes string (`'address'`). It is not, as you may guess by now.

If you need to map all users by address, you can use [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

```
User.where(id: [1,2,3]).pluck(:address)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use: `User.where(id: [1,2,3]).map(&:address)` which will return an array containing the addresses.

And you can use `User.where(id: [1,2,3]).map(&:address).map(&:present?)` if you want an array with true or false value